# ¿Se pueden asignar cadenas a un arreglo después de la declaración?

Tags: c

Necesito hacer primero la declaración y después la asignación porque de la siguiente manera no me sirve:

```
char ingredientes[12][30] = {"Manzana\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"};
```

Lo que quiero hacer es dividirlo en dos procesos, primero declaración y luego asignación, por ejemplo:

```
char ingredientes[12][30];
   ingredientes = {"Manzana\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"};
```

Aquí está el programa completo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){

char ingredientes[12][30] = {"Manzana\n", "Guayaba\n", "Fresa\n"};
    for(size_t i = 0; i<=3; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j<=15; j++)
            printf("%c", ingredientes[i][j]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quiero declarar el arreglo dentro de una estructura e inicializarlo fuera de la estructura en la función principal

Comment: Ese último detalle que has agregado como comentario, deberías de incluirlo en la misma pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ¿Se pueden asignar cadenas a un arreglo después de la declaración?

No, en C no se puede (tal vez en otros lenguajes como [Pawn](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawn) si puedas :D).

> > Quiero declarar el arreglo dentro de una estructura e inicializarlo fuera de la estructura en la función principal

Lenguaje C permite inicializar el array al momento de inicializar la estructura.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char ingredientes[10][30];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct A a = 
    {
        1, 
        3,
        {
            "Manzana\n", 
            "Pera\n",
            "Guayaba\n",
            "Fresa\n"
        }
    };
    
    //Imprime los 4 ingredientes.
    for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
        printf(a.ingredientes[i]);
    return 0;
}
```